# Displaying an external image file on a remote server in a local SAS session

Tags: image, sas

I've used SAS to generate a gif image on a remote server, by remote submitting code from a local SAS session. The macro that was used to create the gif image is designed to run only on the remote server, i.e. it's called within an rsubmit block:

```
rsubmit;
%mymacro(params);
endrsubmit;
```

Is there a way of making the image display in the results area of my local sas session without running any local code? If I did, I could use proc download and then tell SAS to open the image using an external application, but I'd prefer to keep everything contained in the remote macro if possible.

To clarify: the remote session is on a server running Solaris, and the local session is on my PC running Windows. The remote macro creates an external gif image file on the Solaris server, via this sort of method:

```
filename graph '/path/to/my/image.gif';
goptions xpixels = 1280 ypixels = 1024 gsfname = graph device = gif;
proc gplot *etc etc*
```

The chart in question is heavily customised and contains quite a lot of detail, so I'm effectively supersampling in SAS to make it look better when scaled down. Using the grlink graphics device doesn't seem to produce high enough resolution images, so I tried gif.

Bonus points if someone can come up with a method that will work for external image files that haven't been produced by SAS, or by a previous bit of code!

Comment: Sorry; question is not clear. From what client is this code submitted? And what do you mean by "a gif image"; are you creating an external file on the "remote server".  What does your macro do?

Answer (score 2):

You can tell the remote process to write graphics output to a catalog.  You can use the INHERITLIB= option to give a remote process access to a local library.  Therefore, write the remote graphics output into a local catalog.

```
%let host = remote-host 7551;
signon host user="me" password="mypassword";

libname output "e:\temp";

rsubmit host cwait=no inheritlib=(output);
   %macro runme();
      ods html gpath=output.remotepngs;

      data test;
      do x=1 to 100;
         y = 5*x + rannor(0);
         output;
      end;
      run;

      proc sgplot data=test;
      series x=x y=y;
      run;
      ods html close;
   %mend;

   %runme();
endrsubmit;

waitfor host;
signoff host;
```

This creates a catalog in E:\temp that contains the .png file from SGPLOT.

Comment: Good and useful answer, assuming that's what the OP needs. The question mentioned a "gif" so one can assume it's an external file. +1 from me anyway!

Comment: This looks as though it will probably work - however I'm not sure whether it's possible to give the image a custom file name and still include it in the html output.

Comment: I primarily use GTL instead of GRAPH.  I'm looking through the GRAPH docs and I will update if I find.  If you are OK with the default grseg files, you can use the `gout=` option in PROC GPLOT to write to a catalog.

Comment: If you don't end up getting a better answer, i'd post this to [communities.sas.com](http://communities.sas.com/) as rob allison probably can give you a solution if one exists.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a PROC DOWNLOAD submitted to the remote server...

```
proc download infile="/path/to/file.gif" outfile="c:\local\file.gif" binary status=no ; 
run ;
```

I'd also suggest using a better image format, e.g. PNG. Not sure if SAS supports TIFFs!

Comment: I've explicitly stated that I'm looking for alternatives to proc download - this will certainly get the image onto my local machine, but it won't help me view it within SAS using only remotely processed code. Also, gif is perfectly adequate in this case - the vast majority of images produced via sas contain fewer than 100 distinct colours.